# Sum of the perimeters of the squares intersecting the main diagonal

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

This question is from an old Russian contest:

> The unit square $ABCD$ is divided into $10^{12}$ smaller squares (not necessarily equal). Prove that the sum of the perimeters of all the smaller squares intersecting the main diagonal $AC$ is not greater than 1500.

It is possible to divide $ABCD$ in a way such that all squares intersect the main diagonal in at least one point. To do this divide $ABCD$ into four equal smaller squares. A 'diagonal' square is one whose main diagonal belongs to $AC$.

Then divide each of the two diagonal squares into four smaller equal squares. The other two squares that are not 'diagonal' are let unchanged. Repeat this subdivision of diagonal squares into four smaller squares until we have $10^{12}$ squares.

I think that the process above maximize the sum of the perimeters asked, however I don't know how to prove this.

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: the subsquares must be a partition of the unit square?

Comment: also how are we to count squares? does the union of four squares with sides $\frac{1}{4}$ constitute a square with side $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @MichaelChirico: Yes for the 1st question. No for the 2nd. If for example we divide ABCD into four smaller squares of side 1/2 then we have a total of 4 squares, not 5.

Comment: i think you're right, but i don't know how to prove it beyond to point out that any other arrangement of squares must have strictly less total perimeter (of diagonal-touching squares)

Comment: and unfortunately the infinite sum of dividing the square like this is divergent--so we can't say it's ALWAYS below 1500 because it's above there after 400 or so such divisions...

Answer (score 0):

As I'm re-reading this it's a bit graceless, but here goes:

I think that we have to use your "diagonal" squares exclusively can be taken as given--it's all but obvious that cutting any off-diagonal squares is strictly dominated by cutting an on-diagonal square, because doing so a) adds nothing to the relevant perimeter and b) moves us closer to the constraint on total squares.

This question, then, is about choosing among all partitions of diagonal squares and showing that no arrangement of $10^{12}$ squares can exceed the stated total perimeter.

Let's start from this:

Suppose we're at a given partition of the square into sub-squares $S_1,\ldots,S_k$, which have sides $s_1,\ldots,s_k$, respectively. Then the total perimeter at this stage is $4\sum_j s_j$.

Proceeding, we can only crack one of the $k$ squares, say $l$, into 4 sub-squares, each of which will have side $\frac{s_l}{2}$. Thus the perimeter after this will become $4\sum_j s_j+4s_l$.

Thus the total perimeter's increase each time we add 3 squares is bounded by how large we can make $s_l$. (also, as a sanity check, note that since we start with 1 square and add 3 each time, we must have $10^{12} \equiv 1 \mod 3$, which is true).

How large the maximal $s_l$ can be is decreasing logarithmically. To see this, let's start from the beginning and change notation slightly; now we'll use $S^n_i$ to denote the $i$th square of side length $2^{-n}$ in our partition. So our initial square is $S^0_1$ and it can only be split at the second step into $S^1_1,S^1_2,S^1_3,S^1_4$.

Here, it is obvious that the maximal $s_l$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ because all squares are the same, but it's key to notice that in the next step, we'll have a choice between $s=\frac{1}{2}$ and $s=\frac{1}{4}$; $s=\frac{1}{2}$ will be again be maximal, but as subdividing any more side-$\frac{1}{2}$ squares would create off-diagonal squares, the next $s_l$ must be $\frac{1}{4}$.

Now we've got $S^1_{1:2}$ and $S^2_{1:8}$. Using similar logic, we can see that only half of these can be broken into on-diagonal squares, so that we'll have $s_l=\frac{1}{4}$ four times. Continuing, we'll have $s_l=\frac{1}{8}$ eight times, and so on.

Thus, the total perimeter after $M$ optimal breaks is: $4 + 4\sum_{m=1}^M s_l^m$, where ${s_l^m}={\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\ldots}$

There are $10^{12}$ squares after $\frac{10^{12}-1}{3}$ breaks. So the maximal total perimeter is:

$4+4(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})+4(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4})+4(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8})+\cdots$

$=4+4+4+4+\cdots$

Since $\log_2((10^{12}-1)/3+1)+1\approx 43$, the perimeter is less than 4*43=172.

Comment: How do you know that the required sum for $k+3$ squares is maximized when we divide a diagonal square of the configuration of $k$ squares? Is it true that all configurations of $k+3$ squares come from dividing one of the squares of a $k$-squares configuration?

Comment: Yes--in fact, we can pick any of the $k$ squares to divide, but then $s_l=0$, i.e. we contribute nothing to the total perimeter because the extra squares created share nothing with the perimeter (caveat--there may be one square still touching the diagonal, but the perimeter contribution is cut in half, at best)

Comment: You did not prove that among all partitions of $ABCD$ into $10^{12}$ squares, the one you described above is the one that maximizes the required sum, although your bound is much better than 1500.

Comment: true that... WIP status on my answer...

Comment: It's not true that all configurations of k+3 squares come from dividing one of the squares of a k-squares configuration. My previous example is not a good one. Anyway divide $ABCD$ into 16 equal squares of side $1/4$. Join the 4 central smaller squares and form one single central square of side $1/2$. We have now a partition of 13 squares that does not come from any partition having 10 squares.